# Add exit button in the draweLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, android-menu

Very good, I am delighted with this great forum.
I managed to solve almost all my doubts on.

But now I have a question that I can not solve.

In my app I have a set drawerLayout. Works perfectly, but I want put down the list button to exit the app.
I had thought about doing that when you had clicked "Exit", open a Fragment with the following code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SalirFragment.this.getActivity().finish();
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

But this code is causing the app to close when opened.

Anyone have any suggestions?
Thank you very much to all

Comment: do you want to close all your activities at one on click on exit button?

Comment: Yes, I want to close the entire app with a button on the drawerLayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to close all the previous activities.There some changes have to be made in the application

onclick of button start the activity that starts when you launch the application and which is there in activity stack. Like below.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("Exit me", true);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
```

Then in that activity lets say "MainActivity" onCreate() method add this to finish the MainActivity

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    if( getIntent().getBooleanExtra("Exit me", false)){
        finish();
        return; // add this to prevent from doing unnecessary stuffs
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering quickly

Sorry but I do not quite understand what you've given me. No where to put it

Comment: I have written there ,places where you have to place the code.

Comment: Sorry, you were right. Everything went perfect.
Thank you very much.